# Length of the audiofile

Tags: iphone

How to find the total duration of the audiofile playing so that i can program to display the contents of the audiofile in viewcontrollers according to the time.

```
if ([audioPlayer currentTime] ==11){
    [self performSelector:@selector(viewController) withObject:nil]; 

    } else {

        if ([audioPlayer currentTime] ==23){
            [self performSelector:@selector(secondViewController) withObject:nil];  

        }
```

Comment: What framework are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using [`AVAudioPlayer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008067), you can use it's [`duration`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAudioPlayer/duration) property to retrieve the length of the loaded audio file in seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Use the AudioFileServices functions...

```
NSURL *afUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath];
AudioFileID fileID;
OSStatus result = AudioFileOpenURL((CFURLRef)afUrl, kAudioFileReadPermission, 0, &fileID);
UInt64 outDataSize = 0;
UInt32 thePropSize = sizeof(UInt64);
result = AudioFileGetProperty(fileID, kAudioFilePropertyEstimatedDuration, &thePropSize, &outDataSize);
AudioFileClose(fileID);
```

for more info refer these links.. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#codinghowtos/AudioAndVideo/_index.html 
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/musicaudio/reference/AudioFileConvertRef/Reference/reference.html

EDIT: This is to get the length of file even if it is not associated with the AVPlayer.. so you can populate a list ... hoping this helps somebody.. :D